# Insert by using stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

Here is my problem. I have this script wich have to insert data in 2 different tables in database.

```
<html>
<body bgcolor=#005b96>
<?php
    include "database.php";

    $ime=$_POST["p_ime"];
    $prezime=$_POST["p_prezime"];
    $broj_telefona=$_POST["p_broj_telefona"];
    $datum_rodjenja=$_POST["p_datum_rodjenja"];
    $broj_vozacke=$_POST["p_broj_vozacke"];
    $grad="";
    $connection1=mysql_connect("localhost","Admin","rentacar") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("rentacar",$connection1) or die(mysql_error());
    $selectQuery="SELECT idgrad, ime_grada from grad";
    $result=mysql_query($selectQuery,$connection1) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        if($_POST["p_grad"]==$row["ime_grada"]){
        $grad=$row["idgrad"];
        }
    }
    if ($grad=="")
        header("Location:formaGrad.html");
    if ($ime!="" || $grad!=""){

    $connection2=mysql_connect("localhost","Admin","rentacar") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("rentacar",$connection2) or die(mysql_error());
    "INSERT INTO korisnik VALUES
                (NULL,"."\"".$ime."\","."\"".$prezime."\",".$broj_telefona.",\"".$datum_rodjenja."\",".$broj_vozacke.",".$grad.")";
    mysql_query($insertQuery,$connection2) or die (mysql_error());
    }
    else{
        echo "<br><br><h1 align=\"center\">Nisu unešeni zahtjevani podaci</h1>";
    }
    $connection3=mysql_connect("localhost","Admin","rentacar") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("rentacar",$connection3) or die(mysql_error());
    $idkorisnik=mysql_insert_id($connection3);
    $idvozilo=$_POST["p_id_vozilo"];
    $datum_iznajmljivanja=$_POST["p_datum_preuzimanja"];
    $datum_vracanja=$_POST["p_datum_preuzimanja"];
    $insertQuery2="INSERT INTO iznajmljivanje VALUES
                (NULL,".$idkorisnik.",".$idvozilo.",\"".$datum_iznajmljivanja."\",\"".$datum_vracanja."\")";
    mysql_query($insertQuery2,$connection3) or die (mysql_error());
    ?>
</body> 
</html>
```

In this code everything works fine. But i want to insert data in 1st table using stored procedure in MySQL.
So when i put:

```
$insertQuery="call dodajKorisnikaProvjera("."\"".$ime."\","."\"".$prezime."\",".$broj_telefona.",\"".$datum_rodjenja."\",".$broj_vozacke.",".$grad.")";
```

instead:

```
$insertQuery="INSERT INTO korisnik VALUES
                (NULL,"."\"".$ime."\","."\"".$prezime."\",".$broj_telefona.",\"".$datum_rodjenja."\",".$broj_vozacke.",".$grad.")";
```

I got this msg: "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`rentacar`.`iznajmljivanje`, CONSTRAINT `iznajmljivanje-korisnik` FOREIGN KEY (`korisnik_id`) REFERENCES `korisnik` (`idkorisnik`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)"
So 1st insert work again, i got user data in 1st table. But 2nd insert doesn't work?

Whats wrong? Please help if u can.

Here is code of stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `dodajKorisnikaProvjera`(
    IN p_ime varchar(15),
    IN p_prezime varchar(15),
    IN p_broj_telefona int,
    IN p_datum_rodjenja date,
    IN p_broj_vozacke int,
    IN p_grad_id int
)
BEGIN
if TIMESTAMPDIFF(year,p_datum_rodjenja,CURDATE()) >=18 then

    INSERT into korisnik(
    ime,
    prezime,
    broj_telefona,
    datum_rodjenja,
    broj_vozacke,
    grad_id)
     VALUES(
    p_ime,
    p_prezime,
    p_broj_telefona,
    p_datum_rodjenja,
    p_broj_vozacke,
    p_grad_id
    );
    else
    select'Korisnik mora imati vise od 18 godina.';
    end if;

END
```

Table "korisnik" has primary key "idkorisnik". And table "iznajmljivanje" had foreign key "korisnik_id" which references to "idkorisnik".
I discovered that mysql_insert_id($connection2) does not give number. I don't know why, because i can see "idkorisnik" in table. :/
When i put: $idkorisnik=mysql_insert_id($connection2); right after mysql_query(), mysql_insert_id() give back 0 :/

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Thank you for that, i know it, but its not my problem right now.

Comment: obviously you're tryign to insert an orphan record. but since you've provided no details about table/FK structure, we can't help you.